# Spring / DbUnit closes connection after one test

Tags: spring, oracle, datasource, spring-test-dbunit

So, we need to write integration tests for our **Java-configurated Spring Application (3.2.3) with an Oracle data base**. There's a separate schema which gets populated by **Spring-test-DbUnit** and the first test runs without any problems. All the other following tests, no matter if they're in the same class or not, fail due to a closed connection:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: closed connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3423)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3398)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.AbstractBatchStatement.<init>(AbstractBatchStatement.java:50)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.SimpleStatement.<init>(SimpleStatement.java:49)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.PreparedStatementFactory.createBatchStatement(PreparedStatementFactory.java:57)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:85)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:348)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Here's our data source:

```
@Override
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()
{
    String conString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    String username = "john";
    String password = "doe";

    Driver driver = new OracleDriver();
    SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource(driver, conString, username, password);

    return dataSource;
}
```

And this is a sample integration test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { IntegrationTestConfiguration.class })
@ActiveProfiles(Constants.PROFILE_INTEGRATION)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class, ForeignKeyDisabler.class })
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "oracleConnection")
@DatabaseSetup("/database/snapshot/snapshot1.xml")
public class IntegrationTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private NewsService newsService;


    @Test
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void testSpringConfiguration()
    {
        this.assertNewsSize(1);

        News news1 = new News();
        news1.setTitle("Test News 1");
        News savedNews1 = this.newsService.save(news1);
        Assert.assertTrue(savedNews1.getId() > 0);

        News news2 = new News();
        news2.setTitle("Test News 2");
        News savedNews2 = this.newsService.save(news2);
        Assert.assertTrue(savedNews2.getId() > 0);

        News news3 = new News();
        news3.setTitle("Test News 3");
        News savedNews3 = this.newsService.save(news3);
        Assert.assertTrue(savedNews3.getId() > 0);

        this.assertNewsSize(4);
    }


    @Test
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void testSpringConfigurationAgain()
    {
        this.assertNewsSize(1);

        News news1 = new News();
        news1.setTitle("Test News 1");
        News savedNews1 = this.newsService.save(news1);
        Assert.assertTrue(savedNews1.getId() > 0);

        News news2 = new News();
        news2.setTitle("Test News 2");
        News savedNews2 = this.newsService.save(news2);
        Assert.assertTrue(savedNews2.getId() > 0);

        News news3 = new News();
        news3.setTitle("Test News 3");
        News savedNews3 = this.newsService.save(news3);
        Assert.assertTrue(savedNews3.getId() > 0);

        this.assertNewsSize(4);
    }


    private void assertNewsSize(int newsSize)
    {
        List<News> allNews = this.newsService.getNews();
        Assert.assertEquals(newsSize, allNews.size());
    }
}
```

Might this be problem of the Spring's database connection behavior to close a connection after committing/rolling back a transaction? If yes, how can I solve this? My last try was to create transaction on class/method base but without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your `ForeignKeyDisabler.class` do? Are you sure the chain of listeners is correct?

Comment: It disables the foreign key constraints as some data have a circular relation and there cannot be inserted on a one-row-by-table basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to freakman**, we've got a solution that seems to work for us:

We created our own classes

- `OurOwnDbUnitTestExecutionListener.java`
- `OurOwnDbUnitRunner.java`

based on Spring-test-DbUnit's

- `com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java`
- `com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.java`

classes. **Note that the package name for our classes must be equal due to the use of package-scoped classes.** Since the listener uses the runner in a non-configurable manner, we use our own DbUnit runner:

`private static OurOwnDbUnitRunner runner = new OurOwnDbUnitRunner();`

The runner is modified so it does not close the connections after completing a test method. Line 116 is removed:

`// testContext.getConnections().closeAll();`

Finally, we use our modified DbUnitTestExecutionListener in our test class:
`@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    OurOwnDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class, // <<< this does the trick
    ForeignKeyDisabler.class })`

Answer (score 2):

I believe its connected to your `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class` which is some kind of equivalent of
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html .

> Test annotation which indicates that the ApplicationContext associated with a test is dirty and should be closed: 
>   ...
>
> after each test method in the current test class, when declared at the
>   class level with class mode set to AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD

so probably spring is closing your beans after 1st test method. Maybe its easier to just clean up database in @AfterMethod method? It would run after each test.

Comment: I hadn't inspected the TestExecutionListeners yet. So I did and a glance at `DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class` revealed that there is a `afterTestMethod()` that closes all connections: `finally {testContext.getConnections().closeAll();} // (DbUnitRunner.class:94)`. Maybe I need another DbUnitRunner....

Comment: I gave you +1 for leading me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring-test-dbunit, another solution might be to provide a dbUnitDatabaseconnection that overwrites the close-method:

```
@Bean
public IDatabaseConnection dbUnitDatabaseConnection(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
    return new CustomDatabaseConnection(dataSource.getConnection());
}

private static class CustomDatabaseConnection extends DatabaseConnection {
    public CustomDatabaseConnection(Connection connection) throws DatabaseUnitException {
        super(connection);
    }


    @Override
    public void close() {
        // don't close the connection
    }
}
```